# How do I charge my USB-C device with my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging

I have a Nexus 5x (Android phone). It uses a USB-C charging cord. When I plug my USB-charging cord into my phone and into a PC I own, the PC charges the phone (as expected). When I instead insert the USB-C cord into my phone and the other end into my MacBook Pro, the phone charges the MacBook.

This is backwards to me. How do I charge my phone from my MacBook?

Comment: now that is interesting, the big bro sucks up the little guy

Comment: actually that is not possible. to charge your mac you need at least 12 Volt, while the Phone can only produce 5 Volt. Double check your observation and let us know why do you think it is the way.

Comment: Does the same behaviour occur if the MacBook Pro is plugged in to charge?

Comment: @Buscar Ill have to double check my observation, but I'm pretty sure I see the "lightning symbol" appear over the battery icon on the MacBook Pro. jackgmarch good question ill have to check that and post an edit with that info

Comment: "lightning symbol"  over the iPhone battery ? Does the Mac shows it as well ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have this problem. I connect my Android to my Macbook using the USB C cable and the Macbook says "Charging" and the screen brightness increases. It _is_ possible.